# Enable console window to show exception error details

Tags: c#, console

I have coded a simple `ArgumentException` as:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty");
            }
```

Now when I run the program with an Empty  String to test if this exception is functioning, debugger takes me back to MS Visual Studio on this following line:

```
throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty");
```

while I actually expect the `Console` to show me the error message with its details inside the console window. `Console` is rather showing an empty window.

Any idea how to enable exception error details to display inside a console window?

Comment: press F5 to run without debug mode.

Comment: No, actually this IS the expected behaviour. you throw an exception, it will show in code in the debugger. but if you do not run within the debugger, then you will see the errors in the Console Window before your app crashes (as you don't handle the exception). you could however follow this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ahmedilyas how come this tutorial I am watching is showing error details inside console window with error line number and all?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary same behavior with F5.

Comment: @Rehan I think what M.kazemAkhgary meant was `Shift + F5` or Debug->Start Without Debugging

Comment: @cubrr `shift+f5` has no operation linked to it in MS Visual Studio.

Comment: @Rehan My apologies, I meant `Ctrl + F5`. The shortcut can be seen in the Debug tab.

Answer (score 2):

```
  throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty");
```

If you throw an exception in your code and there is no try/catch statement in any of the calling methods then your program will unconditionally crash.  What you see happening when you run with a debugger (F5) is supposed to be *helpful*.  It lets you diagnose the reason your program is about to crash.  Albeit that this particular case shouldn't stump you much, you'll like it lot more when you didn't expect the exception.

If you run without a debugger (Ctrl+F5) then what will happen depends on the .NET version.  For v2.0 through 3.5 you will *not* get any diagnostic.  The Windows WER dialog pops up, telling the user that the program crashed with a message that resembles "ConsoleApplication1 stopped working".  Offering to tell Microsoft about the crash so they can fix bugs in their code.  Not useful :)

If you run on v4.0 and up then the CLR will print the exception message and a stack trace to the console window, then the WER dialog shows up.  Probably what you like.

In general, you do not want to let it get this far and ensure a reasonable diagnostic message is generated regardless of the .NET version.  Without the WER dialog, it is too much of a "you failed" stigma.  You do so by subscribing the AppDomain.UnhandledException event, like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ReportUnhandledException;
        }
        // Rest of code
        //...
        throw new Exception("Kaboom");   // Test
    }

    private static void ReportUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("We're very sorry, this program unexpectedly failed.");
        Console.WriteLine("Please include the following information in your support request:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Please press any key to end the program");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Lots more things you can do with this code, like logging the exception so there is a permanent record of it.  Or emailing the info so you'll know what is happening with your code without you being on-site, helping you to make your app bullet-proof.

Note the Debugger.IsAttached check in this snippet.  It ensures that the debugger remains helpful to diagnose unhandled exceptions.  You can remove that check to get what you asked for.  You shouldn't.

Comment: You wrote: "If you run on v4.0 and up then the CLR will print the exception message and a stack trace to the console window, then the WER dialog shows up." This was my question and this is what I expected but Ms Visual Studio is rather breaking when this situation reaches and no exception message and a stack trace was being printed on the console. `Ctrl + F5` answered my question.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to explain why this is entirely *expected* behavior and not "rather breaking".  Well, gave it a shot, might be useful to somebody else.  Looks like you already added the "just press the right key" answer, you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have to confess your effort cannot go unappreciated. It has surely shed light on the given question from much deeper and a very effective aspect. Thank you for your time and input.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an exception for `ArgumentException`s by opening the menu Debug -> Exceptions (`Ctrl + D, E`). Untick both "Thrown" and "User-unhandled".

Now Visual Studio will not break when an ArgumentException is thrown.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Ms Visual Studio is still breaking after I have unticked both "thrown" and "User-Defined" boxes under `System.ArgumentException`.